# Околотелефонный

Tags: словообразование

Возможно ли сказать "околотелефонный" (например, о блокноте)? Или будет "около телефонный", или вообще такое сочетание с прилагательным невозможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое слово с появлением моды на телефоны получило некоторое распространение в неформальной речи, но его правильное применение, скорее всего, должно ограничиваться абстрактными случаями, такими как "околотелефонная тематика" - по аналогии со словом *околонаучный*. Если же речь идёт о связанных постоянной близостью предметах, естественнее образовывать новое слово с приставкой *при-* (например, *прикроватный* коврик - так давно говорят о некоторых продаваемых предметах; *Придорожная аллея* - из топонимики и т.п.), т.е. *прителефонный*. Но, пока такое слово не прижилось, нужно считаться с тем, что восприниматься оно будет с настороженностью; проще сослаться на *блокнот при телефоне*.